# Dropdown going off to the out of the Header for RTL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have used below jQuery code for stop dropdown going off to the out of the Header. and It is working fine in normal LTR version.

but, **I want to solution for RTL version.** How can i do it?

**jQuery**

```
$('.primary-menu .dropdown-menu').each(function() {
        var menu = $('#header .header-row').offset();
        var dropdown = $(this).parent().offset();

        var i = (dropdown.left + $(this).outerWidth()) - (menu.left + $('#header .header-row').outerWidth());

        if (i > 0) {
            $(this).css('margin-left', '-' + (i) + 'px');
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<header id="header">
<div class="container">
  <div class="header-row">
    <div class="header-column justify-content-start"> 
      
      <div class="logo me-3"> ..... </div>
      
      <!-- Primary Navigation
      ============================== -->
      <nav class="primary-menu navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div id="header-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown dropdown-mega"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Pages</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <div class="dropdown-mega-content">
                    ........
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!-- Primary Navigation end --> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I have try below something But, This is not working**

```
$('.primary-menu .dropdown-menu').each(function() {
        var menu = $('#header .header-row').offset();
        var dropdown = $(this).parent().offset();

        var i = (dropdown.right + $(this).outerWidth()) - (menu.right + $('#header .header-row').outerWidth());

        if (i > 0) {
            $(this).css('margin-right', '-' + (i) + 'px');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right offset is: `window's width - ( element left offset + element outer width)`

So, I have find final solution:

```
$('.primary-menu .dropdown-menu').each(function() {
    var menu = $('#header .header-row').offset();
    var dropdown = $(this).parent().offset();
    
    var rightMenu = ($(window).width() - (menu.left + $('#header .header-row').outerWidth()));
    var rightDropdown = ($(window).width() - (dropdown.left + $(this).parent().outerWidth()));
        
    var i = (rightDropdown + $(this).outerWidth()) - (rightMenu + $('#header .header-row').outerWidth());

    if (i > 0) {
        $(this).css('margin-right', '-' + (i) + 'px');
    }
});
```